# HTL AEM conditional OR operator issue

Tags: aem, sightly

I want to be able to use the "||" OR operator in this context

inside a schema, i have two dates I need to pull from the JCR content if the value in the field has not been the author

```
 <script type="application/ld+json" >
"datePublished": "${properties.datePublishedArticle @context="html" ||'yyyy-MM-dd' @ format=currentPage.lastModified }",
"dateModified": "${properties.dateModifiedArticle @ context="html" || 'yyyy-MM-dd' @ format=currentPage.lastModified}"
</script>
```

org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:

```
mismatched input '@' expecting {'}', '.', 'in', '&&', '||', ',', '['} in line 67 where datepublished is located.
```

In order words, if author has not authored a value, it will take the value from the jcr content. They work fine when done separately.
Do not understand the error that is indicating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use it like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" >
    "datePublished": "${properties.datePublishedArticle ||'yyyy-MM-dd' @ context="html", format = currentPage.lastModified }",
    "dateModified": "${properties.dateModifiedArticle || 'yyyy-MM-dd' @ context="html", format = currentPage.lastModified}"
</script>
```

I would think that the error is happening because you shouldn't be repeating the '@' block in the same HTL statement.

Comment: It worked! Did not see a problem with @ in the same statement

Answer (score 2):

Although @atgar's solution does not throw an error, I think it does not do what the author asked for: output either the authored date or the JCR (`lastModified`) date.

Something like this would be closer to what he needs:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" >
    "datePublished": "${'yyyy-MM-dd' @ context='html', format = (properties.datePublishedArticle ? properties.datePublishedArticle : currentPage.lastModified) }",
    "dateModified": "${'yyyy-MM-dd' @ context='html', format = (properties.dateModifiedArticle ? properties.dateModifiedArticle : currentPage.lastModified)}"
</script>
```

Please note, when using [HTL date formatting](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1222-dates), the actual values should be in the `format` option.

Comment: in HTL "||" the OR operations take the second value if first value is empty.

Comment: for example currently when the author has not enter a date value manually, the HTL automatically updates the HTML to show the jcr values, but as soon as there is a valued field in the dialog box, then that value will overwrite the JCR value.